# stop and begin at the beginning after wrong input

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm learning C# atm and I don't know how to do the following :

```
while (points > 0)
{
    String input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    if (input != true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("wrong number!");
        // here it should stop the following code and start again at the beginning at the while-loop.
    }
    // code if number is correct
```

like a "stop;", thanks for help!

Comment: `continue` starts the loop over again.  `break` breaks out of it.  The [documentation for `while`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx) states that, although subtly.

Comment: Add an `else` for when it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

`continue` is the keyword you are looking for. Further reading:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use `continue` keyword to achieve this:-

```
while (points > 0)
{
    string input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("wrong number!");
        continue;
    }
}
```